# How to move files to Folder using spring Integation SFTP Gateway?

Tags: spring-integration, sftp

Requirement: We are trying to implement an application and its functionality is to move a file from inbound folder  to process folder over sftp with spring sftp outbound gateway. We have implemented sftp outbound gateway as shown below. When we executed application it is giving nothing, i.e., neither exception nor expected output (i.e., file is not moving over sftp)

```
<int-sftp:outbound-gateway id="remoteftpLS"
    session-factory="defaultSftpSessionFactory" request-channel="sftpRequestChannel"
    filename-regex=".*\.txt$" command="mv" expression="'/tmp/datlaa'"
    rename-expression="'/tmp/datlaa/archive'"  />
```

I want to move *.txt files from '/tmp/datlaa to /tmp/datlaa/archive.

Can you please suggest any configuration mistake from my side. or how to make it work?

Thanks

Adding application-context file

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp.xsd">

Answer (score 1):

The `MV` command deals with the **single** file:

> The mv command has no options.
>
> The expression attribute defines the "from" path and the rename-expression attribute defines the "to" path. By default, the rename-expression is headers['file_renameTo']. This expression must not evaluate to null, or an empty String. If necessary, any remote directories needed will be created. The payload of the result message is Boolean.TRUE. The original remote directory is provided in the file_remoteDirectory header, and the filename is provided in the file_remoteFile header. The new path is in the file_renameTo header.

See [Spring Integration Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway).

Your `filename-regex` is ignored there and both `expression` and `rename-expression` should point out to the target file.

If you would like to process a lot of files, like you are specifying with the `filename-regex` consider to use `SFTP LS Gateway -> Spliter -> SFTP MV Gateway`.

Comment: This is not a Spring Integration limitation, SFTP doesn't support wildcards in rename commands.

Comment: Thanks Artem and Gary for the response.
We have gone through the above comments and then try to implement actual requirement. i.e., reading file from sftp and then move the same file to archive folder over sftp. For doing this we have done the below configuration in context file but still file is not moving. Apart from configuration file we have one java main class and it is loading only context file. Can you please suggest do we need to change configuration/add any code in java class.

Comment: Java Class 
'public class SftpGatewaySample {
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SftpGatewaySample.class);
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  ApplicationContext context =
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("outboundGateway.xml");'

Comment: application-context.xml
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapter"
  channel="receiveChannel" session-factory="defaultSftpSessionFactory"
  local-directory="C:\\Users\\RaganiN\\sftp" remote-directory="/tmp/datlaa"
  auto-create-local-directory="true" delete-remote-files="false"
  filename-regex=".*\.txt$">
  <int:poller cron="0/30 * * * * ?">
  </int:poller>
 </int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
<int:channel id="receiveChannel" />
<bean id="messageHandler"  class="com.br.sftp.MessageHandler"/>

Comment: You should move configuration comment to your question as an edit.

Comment: Also add `DEBUG` logging for the `org.springframework.integration` category to see what's going on after the run of your application on each those `30 sec`.

Comment: Hi Artem, 
could you please provide your mail id to send the both configuration and log file.

Comment: Well, my email is confidential for the work purpose. I'm sure you can use any public service to share the resource with me or nay one else. I saw here not one time how guys do that, but don't remember the service. Sorry.

Comment: @ Artem Bilan
Apologies for the inconvenience
I have given the required information at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718613/how-to-move-files-to-folder-using-spring-integation-sftp-gateway-code
Could you please go through and advise us